# How can i have a Toolbar like this ? (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, toolbar

i like this toolbar. where can i find it ?
[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve something (at least very) similar to that with the standard Delphi components:

- add a TControlBar to your form
- set its DrawingStyle to dsGradient
- set its BevelKind to bkNone
- add a TToolBar onto that ControlBar
- set its DrawingStyle to dsGradient
- add a TToolButton onto that ToolBar
- set its Style to tbsDropDown

Comment: Thank you . but i need a blue color toolbar and exactly like that !

Answer (score 3):

You can get one just like that using the free-for-non-commercial-use (and inexpensive for commercial use) Toolbar2000 component, and then adding the SpTBXLib add-on from Silverpoint.

http://www.silverpointdevelopment.com/sptbxlib/index.htm

You should be aware however that what you see on Windows XP with theming enabled will be slightly different than what you see on Windows Vista and Windows 7 with theming enabled, and that if your toolbar paints itself using XP theme support, that it will also stop drawing itself that way, when you turn off the "XP Themes" in Windows, such as when you change Windows to use the classic "Windows 2000" era flat gray theme.

Comment: +1 for SpTBX.  However, Toolbar2000 is not free for commercial usage.  See its website here: http://www.jrsoftware.org/tb2kreg.php .  It is worth paying for, though.  It plus SpTBX are a good UI / toolbar library.

Comment: I keep forgetting that Toolbar2000 isn't licensed for commercial free usage. It is open source, and freely downloaded, but if you fail to pay for it, you are technically doing something illegal (in most countries anyways) and definitely doing something WRONG.  Jordan Russell is a great delphi developer and TB2K is worth the nominal registration fee.

Answer (score 0):

That looks a bit a like a DxBar, part of the VCL Suite by Developer Express.

Answer (score 0):

I found it .
its name is TRzToolbar from Rize Panels componenets ;)